# Exchange 2003 public folder alert?

Tags: exchange-server

Is there a way for a user to receve alerts when a public folder email is moved/replied to or deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked into this and the solution is to go with 3rd parties

http://www.sperrysoftware.com/Outlook/Watch-Outlook-Folders.asp
http://www.mapilab.com/outlook/folders_watch/